# Laravel raw query with complex where not working right

Tags: mysql

A quick on please, i am working on a project and am trying to retrieve ads from a table in which are ads with categories, subcategories and their title.

This is the query:

`SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ads WHERE category = 4 AND subcategory = 79 AND title LIKE '%Samsung%' OR title LIKE '%galaxy%' OR title LIKE '%S4%' ORDER BY IF(title Like '%Samsung%', 1, 0) + IF(title Like '%galaxy%', 1, 0) + IF(title Like '%S4%', 1, 0) DESC LIMIT 25`

The Problem:

The query ignores the category and subcategory where and fetches the record as long as the the title is like the supplied string, i can't seem to figure out what the problem is, please i need help on this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the `LIKE` statements in paranthesis:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM ads
WHERE category = 4
  AND subcategory = 79
  AND (title LIKE '%Samsung%'
       OR title LIKE '%galaxy%'
       OR title LIKE '%S4%')
ORDER BY IF(title LIKE '%Samsung%', 1, 0) + IF(title LIKE '%galaxy%', 1, 0) + IF(title LIKE '%S4%', 1, 0) DESC LIMIT 25
```

Take a look at the [Mysql Operator Precendence Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).